# how to work with a vector of weak references in rust

Tags: rust, weak-references, boxing

I want to to hold array of objects to callback to once some event occurs. I don't need to own the objects and in the case the objects were deallocated that is fine, I can remove the listeners lazily from the container.

conceptually something like this but getting lots of compile/ownership errors:

```
trait EventListener {
  fn event_occured(&mut self, event_name: String); 
}

struct Listener {
  listeners : Vec<Weak<EventListener>>
}

impl Listener {
   fn observe_event(&mut self, listener: impl EventListener) {
      self.listeners.push(Weak(listener)); // how can i box the listener in a weak container
   }
   fn listen_for_events() {

      ... did something here and figured it should broadcast to all listeners ... 
      for listener in self.listeners {
          if listener.is_alive { listener.event_occured(event)} ;  // how to check the weak ref is valid?
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The owner needs to collaborate with this code to allow it to hold weak references. This means that `Listener::observe_event` needs to take either a `Weak<dyn EventListener>` or an `Rc<dyn EventListener>`. (Or the `Arc` equivelents) At the moment its taking an `EventListener` value which will of course be deallocated when `Listener::observe_event` returns.

Comment: can i box it in a strong object with a weak reference? if so how can it be done? i.e.
`struct WeakBox<T: EventListener> { thing: weak<T> } `
and change the vector to:
`listeners : Vec<WeakBox>`

Comment: @AvnerBarr that wouldn't help, to use `Weak` you need to have an `Rc` *somewhere* that actually owns the `EventListener`

Comment: so its impossible to have this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional example based on your posted code (on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fdb5b5bc7558092b321fff39014f8248)):

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

trait EventListener {
  fn event_occured(&self, event_name: &String); 
}

struct Listener {
  listeners : Vec<Weak<dyn EventListener>>
}

impl Listener {
   fn observe_event(&mut self, listener: &Rc<dyn EventListener>) {
      self.listeners.push(Rc::downgrade(listener));
   }
   
   fn listen_for_events(&self) {
        let event = String::new();
        for listener in &self.listeners {
            if let Some(strong_listener) = listener.upgrade() {
                strong_listener.event_occured(&event);
            }
        }
    }
}

struct A {}
impl EventListener for A {
    fn event_occured(&self, _event_name: &String) {
        println!("A");
    }
}

struct B {}
impl EventListener for B {
    fn event_occured(&self, _event_name: &String) {
        println!("B");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Rc<dyn EventListener> = Rc::new(A{});
    let b: Rc<dyn EventListener> = Rc::new(B{});
    
    let mut listener = Listener { listeners: vec![] };
    
    listener.observe_event(&a);
    listener.observe_event(&b);
    
    listener.listen_for_events();
    
    // B goes out of scope
    drop(b);
    
    listener.listen_for_events();
}
```

it prints

```
A
B
A
```

It seems you have some confusion of when `Weak` can be used. It is *not* a mechanism to now when just anything is deallocated. It only works when paired with `Rc`.

Comment: not sure it solves it for 2 reasons
1. The callback should be &mut self (i'll fix the question might have forgotten it)
2. I want the listing to be opt in for existing objects and can't refactor the whole code base to RC every place they are instantiated

Comment: Then you can't have weak references to them. Rust is not Python, everything is not garbage collected by default. You can't have a *weak reference* without a *reference count* (or equivalent)

Comment: I changed the callback mutability because `Rc`s can't provide mutable references to its content safely, you'd need to wrap it in something like a `RefCell` or `Mutex` if that's needed.